# DISLIN library, "dislin.mod" is not a Fortran file

Tags: fortran, mpi

Well, I've just installed DISLIN because I have to use it with Fortran and MPI.
But when i try to run:

```
mpif90 -I/usr/local/dislin/ifc/ -L/usr/local/dislin -ldislin 3-life_parallelo.f90 -o life
```

but it always replies me

> USE DISLIN
>        1 Fatal Error: File 'dislin.mod' opened at (1) is not a GNU Fortran module file

I don't know what to do.. in /ifc folder i have 2 files: dislin.f90 and dislin.mod, the last one is an Audio Amiga SoundTracker (audio/x-mod) filetype. So.. i need a dislin.mod fortran file.. do i have to save it like "dislin.mod.f90"? I don't think so.

UPDATE (Dislin library recompiled with gfortran, i re-run "mpif90 .." see above)

```
/tmp/ccm8YsO3.o: nella funzione "showgrid_":
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x39f): undefined reference to "getlev_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x3b9): undefined reference to "metafl_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x3f0): undefined reference to "page_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x3f5): undefined reference to "disini_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x3fa): undefined reference to "pagera_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x3ff): undefined reference to "nobar_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x404): undefined reference to "intax_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x438): undefined reference to "setgrf_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x46d): undefined reference to "autres_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x4c7): undefined reference to "graf3_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x4db): undefined reference to "ticks_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x4e0): undefined reference to "cross_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x529): undefined reference to "crvmat_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x52e): undefined reference to "endgrf_"
3-life_parallelo.f90:(.text+0x56d): undefined reference to "dwgmsg_"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How I compiled dislin.mod

```
cd /usr/local/dislin/gf/: sudo gfortran -c dislin.f90
cd real64: sudo gfortran -c dislin.f90
```

How I use dislin lib

```
SUBROUTINE showgrid( griglia, numx, numy, nloop )
 USE DISLIN
 IMPLICIT NONE

 INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: griglia(numx,numy)
 INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: numx, numy
 INTEGER, INTENT(IN) :: nloop

 REAL :: extgrid(0:numx+1,0:numy+1)
 INTEGER :: nlev
 CHARACTER(5) :: sloop

 IF ( MAXVAL(griglia)>1 .OR. MINVAL(griglia)<0 ) THEN
  STOP "ERRORE: gli elementi della matrice devono essere 1 o 0"
 END IF

 extgrid( 0 , : )= -1
 extgrid( numx+1 , : )= -1
 extgrid( : , 0 )= -1
 extgrid( : , numy+1 )= -1
 extgrid(1:numx,1:numy)= REAL(griglia(:,:))

 WRITE(UNIT=sloop, FMT='(I4)') nloop

 CALL GETLEV(nlev)
 IF (nlev == 0) THEN
  CALL METAFL('XWIN')
  CALL PAGE(200*numx, 200*numy)
  CALL DISINI()
  CALL PAGERA()
  CALL NOBAR()
  CALL INTAX()
  CALL SETGRF ("NONE", "NONE", "NONE", "NONE")
  CALL AUTRES( (numx+2)*2, (numy+2)*2)
 END IF

 CALL GRAF3(-1., 1., -1., 1., -1., 1., -1., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1.)
 CALL TICKS (0, "XYZ")
 CALL CROSS()
 CALL CRVMAT(extgrid, numx+2, numy+2, 1, 1)
 CALL ENDGRF()


 CALL DWGMSG("Generazione numero"//sloop)

END SUBROUTINE showgrid
```

UPDATE (run mpif90 with gfortran, dislin.mod compiled by gfortran)

> Cannot read module file 'dislin.mod' opened at (1), because it was
>   created by a different version of GNU Fortran

"gfortran --version" and "mpif90 --version" returns me both 4.8.2

mpif90 -v

```
mpif90 for MPICH version 3.0.4
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gfortran
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.8/lto-wrapper
Target: x86_64-linux-gnu
...
gcc version 4.8.2 (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dislin.mod` is the right thing. It is not an Amiga sound file even-though your system reports it as such. It is a Fortran module file, the information about variables and procedures contained in the modules which you compiled are stored there.

However, it seems you compiled DISLIN with a different compiler, than the compiler behind your `mpif90`. Your `mpif90` is gfortran according to the error message. You apparently used a different compiler for the installation.

As `.mod` files produced by different compilers are not compatible, it will not work. Even different versions of the same compiler often cause problems. You must be sure to install the library with the same compiler you intend to use it with later.

If you use a pre-compiled version, you can only use it with the compiler for which it was prepared.

---

In your new problem it appears you do not link the library properly. You must link in the libraries which contain the missing symbol. You should always show the command which produces any error messages, the messages alone are often useless.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81311/discussion-on-answer-by-vladimir-f-dislin-library-dislin-mod-is-not-a-fortran).